# Update the togglebutton status when the realtimedatabase in firebase changes from on / off

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am still learning to use Android Studio, I have difficulty to set the status of the togglebutton in accordance with the realtimedatabase in Firebase, when exiting the application and entering the button again is off when the database is on,
so what I want to ask, when the database is activated, then togglebutton on Android is active and vice versa,
Thank you.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView teks;
DatabaseReference dref;
String status;
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    teks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    Typeface customfont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/jd_led3.ttf");
    teks.setTypeface(customfont);
    teks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            status=dataSnapshot.child("Suhu").getValue().toString();
            teks.setText(status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


    final ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            button.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP);
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("RELAY1_STATUS");
            if(button.isChecked()){
                myRef.setValue("ON");
            }else{
                myRef.setValue("OFF");

            }
        }
    });


    final ToggleButton button1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            button1.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP);
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("RELAY2_STATUS");
            if(button1.isChecked()){
                myRef.setValue("ON");
            }else{
                myRef.setValue("OFF");
            }
        }
    });

    final ToggleButton button2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            button2.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP);
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("RELAY3_STATUS");
            if(button2.isChecked()){
                myRef.setValue("ON");
            }else{
                myRef.setValue("OFF");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

sorry if my post is a mess I am also the first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

ON ONCREATE You will need need to add value event listener like

```
MyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
status=dataSnapshot.child("RELAY2_STATUS").getValue().toString();

if(status.equals("ON"){
button1.isChecked(true)
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
}
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the comment, but when I try it code is error ?

Comment: The problem is resolved, I have edited and added some code, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + status);
            status = dataSnapshot.child("RELAY1_STATUS").getValue().toString();
            if (status.equals("ON")) {
                a.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                a.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: ",error.toException() );
        }
    });
```